# Use external javascript library only in specific child LWC instead of including in VF page

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, libraries

I am trying to use an external JS library for feedback purpose.
When I use the library in a VF page using `<script>` tag by including src="js URL", it works well and I can inspect and see the library.

**VF code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://feedback.smg.com/etrackjslibrary" async="true"></script>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="LightningComponentid" />
    <script>
$Lightning.use("c:LWCApp", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:MainPage",
                {
                    "name" : name
                },
                "lwcId",
                function (cmp) {
                });
        });
    </script>
```

We have embedded LWC inside the VF page and LWC Parent contains a number of child components,
Now the ask is to enable the external js library only on a specific child component, so I have made below changes

1. Removed script tag from VF page.
2. Created static resource and added js in it.
3. Child component changes

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
<c-childLWC>
</template>
```

**Child Template**

```
<template>
    <div lwc:dom="manual"></div>
{template code}
</template>
```

**Child JS**

```
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import surveyFeedback from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/surveyFeedback';

renderedCallback() {
      console.log('inside renderedCallback');
      Promise.all([
          loadScript(this, surveyFeedback)
      ]).then(() => {
          console.log('Feedback called');
      }).catch(error => {
          console.log('Error loading feedback', error);
      });
  }
```

When navigated to the child component and inside renderedCallback it always goes to catch block and throws error as undefined.

Firefox Network screenshot [image]

When using in VF page, the js gets executed by including the script tag and I can see the button which the js adds in the inspector.
[image]

Comment: there isin't much we can do with the amount of information you have shared, please make sure you include a minimum viable code sample for others to reproduce, and more details on the code.

Comment: @glls - Updated the question with more details.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the path of your script is the right one? and that it is not something like `surveyFeedback/fileName.js` or something within those lines?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of the path, the js has been directly uploaded in the static resource

Comment: @glls - Tried already without Promise.all, still same. Checked the browser network, I don't see the script name in chrome & incognito both, but in firefox I can see it with status code 200

Comment: @glls - Updated the post with screenshot

Comment: @Rohit, can you please confirm a few things: 1. Is your static resource public or privately available, 2. JS is case sensitive, so is your static resource name matches the case with "surveyFeedback", 3. Is there any other JS as well in this or any related component, which is getting loaded from static resource.

Comment: @user43598 - Static resource is public, the resource name matches the case and there is no other JS loading from static resource.

Comment: @glls - Can this be an issue with the javascript library, when I checked the code it uses document.querySelectorAll() method which works with the VF page, but, now since it's being included in LWC, would that cause an issue? Just trying to think about it.